# How do i base the value of one attribute to another attribute within the same schema model in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I`m creating a booking system application and i have this schema where i have these attributes

```
  reservedDates: [
    {
      start: { type: Date },
      end: { type: Date },
    }
  ];

slots: { type: Number, required: true },
```

I was planning to connect my slots attribute to my reservedDates attribute in a way that the slots attribute would change everytime an something is added or removed to my reservedDates attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean at the DB level, like a stored proc on an update trigger?  MongoDB does not have this.  But:  If you are connecting the `reservedDates` array to the `slots` field for the length, then perhaps you don't need `slots` at all; just get the `$size` of the `reservedDates` array.